# 1146 Table 'mage.flag' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4.4

Suddenly I started to see this issue below in all URLs in my Magento 2.4.4

```
3 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\TableNotFoundException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage_adt.flag' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `flag`.* FROM `flag` WHERE (`flag`.`flag_code`='staging')
Exception #1 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage_adt.flag' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `flag`.* FROM `flag` WHERE (`flag`.`flag_code`='staging')
Exception #2 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage_adt.flag' doesn't exist

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\TableNotFoundException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage_adt.flag' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `flag`.* FROM `flag` WHERE (`flag`.`flag_code`='staging')
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php:95]
#2 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->query() called at [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:756]
#3 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php:1094]
#4 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->fetchRow() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:333]
#5 Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:543]
#6 Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Flag.php:147]
#7 Magento\Framework\Flag->loadSelf() called at [vendor/magento/module-staging/Model/Update/VersionHistory.php:78]
#8 Magento\Staging\Model\Update\VersionHistory->getFlag() called at [vendor/magento/module-staging/Model/Update/VersionHistory.php:58]
#9 Magento\Staging\Model\Update\VersionHistory->getCurrentId() called at [vendor/magento/module-staging/Model/VersionManager.php:192]
#10 Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager->getCurrentVersionId() called at [vendor/magento/module-staging/Model/VersionManager.php:121]
#11 Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager->getVersion() called at [generated/code/Magento/Staging/Model/VersionManager/Interceptor.php:32]
#12 Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager\Interceptor->getVersion() called at [vendor/magento/module-staging/Model/VersionManager.php:181]
#13 Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager->isPreviewVersion() called at [generated/code/Magento/Staging/Model/VersionManager/Interceptor.php:59]
#14 Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager\Interceptor->isPreviewVersion() called at [generated/code/Magento/Staging/Model/VersionManager/Proxy.php:127]
#15 Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager\Proxy->isPreviewVersion() called at [vendor/magento/module-staging/Plugin/Store/Model/StoreResolver.php:59]
#16 Magento\Staging\Plugin\Store\Model\StoreResolver->aroundGetCurrentStoreId() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#17 Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreResolver/Interceptor.php:23]
#19 Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Interceptor->getCurrentStoreId() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php:160]
#20 Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore() called at [generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManager/Interceptor.php:59]
#21 Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager\Interceptor->getStore() called at [generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php:119]
#22 Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php:30]
#23 Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php:49]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php:69]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php:123]
#26 Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->isHostBackend() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php:106]
#27 Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/AreaList.php:73]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\AreaList->getCodeByFrontName() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:111]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

[image: Magento 2.4.4 database table missing]

How could I check it?

Answer (score 1):

Create flag Table using below query

```
CREATE TABLE `flag` (
  `flag_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Flag Id',
  `flag_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Flag Code',
  `state` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Flag State',
  `flag_data` mediumtext COMMENT 'Flag Data',
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Date of Last Flag Update'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

then process as it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to run the `setup:install` again I found this issue below related to the database permission.

[image: Database permission]

I solved it with these commands in my database, directly from my MySQL Docker container.

```
CREATE USER 'dev'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON magento2.* TO 'dev'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON magento2.* TO 'dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that, I had file permission quickly solved by using `chmod` command.
I finished it by removing the old `env.php` file and running the `setup:install` command again.